# Failed to start Jobtracker and Tasktracker in CDH pseudo cluster

Tags: hadoop

I noticed this problem when I tried to execute map reduce in R and failed to talk to JT and TT. This happened after I changed some config files, but unfortunately, I forgot how to change it back (my bad)!!

1) JT log:

```
2013-08-05 15:14:09,335 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobTracker: STARTUP_MSG: 
/************************************************************
STARTUP_MSG: Starting JobTracker
STARTUP_MSG:   host = rhadoop/172.16.1.39
STARTUP_MSG:   args = []
STARTUP_MSG:   version = 2.0.0-mr1-cdh4.3.0
STARTUP_MSG:   classpath = /etc/hadoop/conf:/usr/local/java/jdk1.7.0_15/lib/tools.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/hadoop-core-2.0.0-mr1-cdh4.3.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/activation-1.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/ant-contrib-1.0b3.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/asm-3.2.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/avro-1.7.4.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/avro-compiler-1.7.4.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/commons-beanutils-1.7.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/commons-beanutils-core-1.8.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/commons-cli-1.2.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/commons-codec-1.4.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/commons-collections-3.2.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/commons-compress-1.4.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/commons-configuration-1.6.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/commons-digester-1.8.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/commons-el-1.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/commons-httpclient-3.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/commons-io-2.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/commons-lang-2.5.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/commons-math-2.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/commons-net-3.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/guava-11.0.2.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/hadoop-fairscheduler-2.0.0-mr1-cdh4.3.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/hsqldb-1.8.0.10.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/jackson-core-asl-1.8.8.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/jackson-jaxrs-1.8.8.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/jackson-mapper-asl-1.8.8.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/jackson-xc-1.8.8.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/jasper-compiler-5.5.23.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/jasper-runtime-5.5.23.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/jaxb-api-2.2.2.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/jaxb-impl-2.2.3-1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/jersey-core-1.8.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/jersey-json-1.8.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/jersey-server-1.8.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/jets3t-0.6.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/jettison-1.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/jetty-6.1.26.cloudera.2.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/jetty-util-6.1.26.cloudera.2.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/jline-0.9.94.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/jsch-0.1.42.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/jsp-api-2.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/jsr305-1.3.9.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/junit-4.8.2.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/kfs-0.2.2.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/kfs-0.3.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/log4j-1.2.17.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/mockito-all-1.8.5.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/paranamer-2.3.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/protobuf-java-2.4.0a.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/servlet-api-2.5.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/snappy-java-1.0.4.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/stax-api-1.0.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/xmlenc-0.52.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/xz-1.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/zookeeper-3.4.5-cdh4.3.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/jsp-2.1/jsp-2.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/jsp-2.1/jsp-api-2.1.jar:/etc/hadoop/conf:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/commons-math-2.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/jasper-compiler-5.5.23.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/commons-net-3.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/jsr305-1.3.9.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/asm-3.2.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/jasper-runtime-5.5.23.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/jsp-api-2.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/jackson-mapper-asl-1.8.8.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/commons-collections-3.2.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/snappy-java-1.0.4.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/commons-el-1.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/commons-beanutils-1.7.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/log4j-1.2.17.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/commons-lang-2.5.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/xz-1.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/jsch-0.1.42.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/commons-httpclient-3.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/jets3t-0.6.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/jaxb-api-2.2.2.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/activation-1.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/jetty-util-6.1.26.cloudera.2.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/commons-digester-1.8.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/avro-1.7.4.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/stax-api-1.0.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/commons-beanutils-core-1.8.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.6.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/mockito-all-1.8.5.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/paranamer-2.3.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/commons-configuration-1.6.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/commons-cli-1.2.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/commons-compress-1.4.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/protobuf-java-2.4.0a.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/jersey-server-1.8.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/jline-0.9.94.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/jetty-6.1.26.cloudera.2.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/xmlenc-0.52.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/junit-4.8.2.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/jersey-core-1.8.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/guava-11.0.2.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/jaxb-impl-2.2.3-1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/servlet-api-2.5.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/jackson-jaxrs-1.8.8.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/commons-io-2.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/commons-codec-1.4.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/jettison-1.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/jersey-json-1.8.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/kfs-0.3.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/jackson-xc-1.8.8.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/zookeeper-3.4.5-cdh4.3.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/jackson-core-asl-1.8.8.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/.//hadoop-annotations-2.0.0-cdh4.3.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/.//hadoop-common-2.0.0-cdh4.3.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/.//hadoop-common.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/.//hadoop-common-2.0.0-cdh4.3.0-tests.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/.//hadoop-annotations.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/.//hadoop-auth.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/.//hadoop-auth-2.0.0-cdh4.3.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/./:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/jsr305-1.3.9.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/asm-3.2.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/jasper-runtime-5.5.23.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/jsp-api-2.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/jackson-mapper-asl-1.8.8.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/commons-daemon-1.0.3.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/commons-el-1.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/log4j-1.2.17.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/commons-lang-2.5.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/jetty-util-6.1.26.cloudera.2.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/commons-cli-1.2.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/protobuf-java-2.4.0a.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/jersey-server-1.8.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/jline-0.9.94.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/jetty-6.1.26.cloudera.2.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/xmlenc-0.52.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/jersey-core-1.8.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/guava-11.0.2.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/servlet-api-2.5.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/commons-io-2.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/commons-codec-1.4.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/zookeeper-3.4.5-cdh4.3.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/jackson-core-asl-1.8.8.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/.//hadoop-hdfs-2.0.0-cdh4.3.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/.//hadoop-hdfs.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/.//hadoop-hdfs-2.0.0-cdh4.3.0-tests.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/.//*:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/./:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/commons-math-2.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/jasper-compiler-5.5.23.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/commons-net-3.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/jsr305-1.3.9.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/asm-3.2.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/jasper-runtime-5.5.23.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/jsp-api-2.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/jackson-mapper-asl-1.8.8.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/commons-collections-3.2.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/snappy-java-1.0.4.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/commons-el-1.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/commons-beanutils-1.7.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/log4j-1.2.17.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/commons-lang-2.5.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/xz-1.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/jsch-0.1.42.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/commons-httpclient-3.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/jets3t-0.6.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/jaxb-api-2.2.2.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/activation-1.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/jetty-util-6.1.26.cloudera.2.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/commons-digester-1.8.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/avro-1.7.4.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/avro-compiler-1.7.4.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/stax-api-1.0.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/commons-beanutils-core-1.8.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/mockito-all-1.8.5.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/paranamer-2.3.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/commons-configuration-1.6.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/commons-cli-1.2.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/commons-compress-1.4.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/protobuf-java-2.4.0a.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/hsqldb-1.8.0.10.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/jersey-server-1.8.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/jline-0.9.94.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/jetty-6.1.26.cloudera.2.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/xmlenc-0.52.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/junit-4.8.2.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/jersey-core-1.8.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/ant-contrib-1.0b3.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/guava-11.0.2.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/jaxb-impl-2.2.3-1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/servlet-api-2.5.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/jackson-jaxrs-1.8.8.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/kfs-0.2.2.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/commons-io-2.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/commons-codec-1.4.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/jettison-1.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/jersey-json-1.8.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/kfs-0.3.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/jackson-xc-1.8.8.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/hadoop-fairscheduler-2.0.0-mr1-cdh4.3.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/zookeeper-3.4.5-cdh4.3.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/jackson-core-asl-1.8.8.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/.//hadoop-ant-2.0.0-mr1-cdh4.3.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/.//hadoop-ant.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/.//hadoop-tools.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/.//hadoop-tools-2.0.0-mr1-cdh4.3.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/.//hadoop-core-2.0.0-mr1-cdh4.3.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/.//hadoop-test.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/.//hadoop-core.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/.//hadoop-test-2.0.0-mr1-cdh4.3.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/.//hadoop-examples-2.0.0-mr1-cdh4.3.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/.//hadoop-examples.jar
STARTUP_MSG:   build = file:///data/1/jenkins/workspace/generic-package-ubuntu64-10-04/CDH4.3.0-Packaging-Hadoop-2013-05-27_19-02-30/hadoop-2.0.0+1357-1.cdh4.3.0.p0.21~lucid/src/hadoop-mapreduce1-project -r Unknown; compiled by 'jenkins' on Mon May 27 19:57:14 PDT 2013
STARTUP_MSG:   java = 1.7.0_15
************************************************************/
2013-08-05 15:14:09,342 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobTracker: registered UNIX signal handlers for [TERM, HUP, INT]
2013-08-05 15:14:14,823 INFO org.apache.hadoop.security.token.delegation.AbstractDelegationTokenSecretManager: Updating the current master key for generating delegation tokens
2013-08-05 15:14:14,836 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobTracker: Scheduler configured with (memSizeForMapSlotOnJT, memSizeForReduceSlotOnJT, limitMaxMemForMapTasks, limitMaxMemForReduceTasks) (-1, -1, -1, -1)
2013-08-05 15:14:14,837 INFO org.apache.hadoop.util.HostsFileReader: Refreshing hosts (include/exclude) list
2013-08-05 15:14:14,838 INFO org.apache.hadoop.security.token.delegation.AbstractDelegationTokenSecretManager: Starting expired delegation token remover thread, tokenRemoverScanInterval=60 min(s)
2013-08-05 15:14:14,850 INFO org.apache.hadoop.security.token.delegation.AbstractDelegationTokenSecretManager: Updating the current master key for generating delegation tokens
2013-08-05 15:14:15,081 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobTracker: Starting jobtracker with owner as mapred
2013-08-05 15:14:15,230 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: Starting Socket Reader #1 for port 8021
2013-08-05 15:14:15,361 WARN org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC: Interface interface org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTrackerManager ignored because it does not extend VersionedProtocol
2013-08-05 15:14:22,145 INFO org.mortbay.log: Logging to org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerAdapter(org.mortbay.log) via org.mortbay.log.Slf4jLog
2013-08-05 15:14:22,306 INFO org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer: Added global filter 'safety' (class=org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer$QuotingInputFilter)
2013-08-05 15:14:22,310 INFO org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer: Added filter static_user_filter (class=org.apache.hadoop.http.lib.StaticUserWebFilter$StaticUserFilter) to context job
2013-08-05 15:14:22,314 INFO org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer: Added filter static_user_filter (class=org.apache.hadoop.http.lib.StaticUserWebFilter$StaticUserFilter) to context logs
2013-08-05 15:14:22,314 INFO org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer: Added filter static_user_filter (class=org.apache.hadoop.http.lib.StaticUserWebFilter$StaticUserFilter) to context static
2013-08-05 15:14:22,689 INFO org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer: Jetty bound to port 50030
2013-08-05 15:14:22,689 INFO org.mortbay.log: jetty-6.1.26.cloudera.2
2013-08-05 15:14:23,908 INFO org.mortbay.log: Started SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:50030
2013-08-05 15:14:24,065 WARN org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration: session.id is deprecated. Instead, use dfs.metrics.session-id
2013-08-05 15:14:24,075 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics.jvm.JvmMetrics: Initializing JVM Metrics with processName=JobTracker, sessionId=
2013-08-05 15:14:24,117 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobTracker: JobTracker up at: 8021
2013-08-05 15:14:24,117 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobTracker: JobTracker webserver: 50030
2013-08-05 15:14:25,374 FATAL org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobTracker: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Wrong FS: file:/var/lib/hadoop-hdfs/cache/mapred/mapred/system, expected: hdfs://rhadoop:8020
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.checkPath(FileSystem.java:625)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.makeQualified(FileSystem.java:445)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobTracker.getSystemDir(JobTracker.java:4174)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobTracker.<init>(JobTracker.java:1941)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobTracker.<init>(JobTracker.java:1747)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobTracker.startTracker(JobTracker.java:305)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobTracker.startTracker(JobTracker.java:297)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobTracker.main(JobTracker.java:4538)

2013-08-05 15:14:25,383 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobTracker: SHUTDOWN_MSG: 
/************************************************************
SHUTDOWN_MSG: Shutting down JobTracker at rhadoop/172.16.1.39
**
```

****************************************************/

2)TT log(exceed body limit, so only I'll only show show errors):

```
2013-08-05 14:55:07,215 WARN org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: TaskTracker local dir file:///var/lib/hadoop-hdfs/cache/mapred/mapred/local error Dir is not readable: file:///var/lib/hadoop-hdfs/cache/mapred/mapred/local, removing from local dirs
2013-08-05 14:55:07,217 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: Can not start task tracker because org.apache.hadoop.util.DiskChecker$DiskErrorException: No mapred local directories are writable
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker$LocalStorage.checkDirs(TaskTracker.java:279)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker.<init>(TaskTracker.java:1710)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker.main(TaskTracker.java:4041)

2013-08-05 14:55:07,225 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: SHUTDOWN_MSG: 
/************************************************************
SHUTDOWN_MSG: Shutting down TaskTracker at rhadoop/172.16.1.39
************************************************************/
```

3) And here is my /etc/hosts file:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
172.16.1.39     rhadoop
```

4) And my config in core-site.xml:

```
<property>
 <name>fs.default.name</name>
 <value>hdfs://rhadoop:8020</value>
 </property>
```

5) And my mapred-site.xml:

```
<configuration>
  <property>
    <name>mapred.job.tracker</name>
    <value>rhadoop:8021</value>
  </property>

  <!-- Enable Hue plugins -->
  <property>
    <name>mapred.jobtracker.plugins</name>
    <value>org.apache.hadoop.thriftfs.ThriftJobTrackerPlugin</value>
    <description>Comma-separated list of jobtracker plug-ins to be activated.
    </description>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>jobtracker.thrift.address</name>
    <value>0.0.0.0:9290</value>
  </property>
</configuration>
```

And one thing to mention is I checked the Wrong FS error for JT online, but most of them are like:

Wrong FS: hdfs:xxxxxxxxxxxxx, expected: xxxxxxxxx

ked But mine is like Wrong FS: file:xxxxxxxxxxx.

Can anyone help me with the configuration thing here?

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem. In file /etc/hadoop/conf/hdfs-site.xml, there is one attribute:

```
<property>
 <name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name>
 <value>/var/lib/hadoop-hdfs/cache/${user.name}</value>
 </property>
```

When I made some change, I carelessly changed the value to:

```
file:///var/lib/hadoop-hdfs/cache/${user.name}
```

which caused my problem!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you do not have proper permissions on the directory **file:///var/lib/hadoop-hdfs/cache/mapred/mapred/local**. Have you changed anything in your **mapred-site.xml** file?Specially the property **mapred.local.dir**?Showing us the JT and TT log files would be helpful.

Comment: I posted more information about the JT log and my mapred-site.xml, hope they can help you to figure out what happened

Comment: I found out what I modified finally. If I set both localhost and rhadoop in /etc/hosts to 127.0.0.1, the R-Hadoop works fine. But I want to access it from remote, so I set rhadoop to 172.16.1.39, then the problem happended. How to solve it?