# Hadoop Yarn job: Wrong FS

Tags: java, hadoop, cloudera-cdh

I installed a cloudera cluster with a vagrant box. 
I get an error when I launch the following example:

```
 hadoop jar /usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples.jar grep input output23 'dfs[a-z.]+'
```

I went to check the log in `/var/log/hadoop-yarn`.
There several log file, in `yarn-yarn-nodemanager-cdh-master.log`, there is the following stackstrace:

```
2015-06-17 11:42:42,398 INFO SecurityLogger.org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: Auth successful for appattempt_1434535025160_0001_000001 (auth:SIMPLE)
2015-06-17 11:42:42,597 INFO  org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.ContainerManagerImpl: Start request for container_1434535025160_0001_01_
000001 by user vagrant
2015-06-17 11:42:42,762 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.ContainerManagerImpl: Creating a new application reference for app appli
cation_1434535025160_0001
2015-06-17 11:42:42,776 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.application.Application: Application application_1434535025160_0001 tran
sitioned from NEW to INITING
2015-06-17 11:42:42,778 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NMAuditLogger: USER=vagrant      IP=10.10.50.5   OPERATION=Start Container Request
TARGET=ContainerManageImpl      RESULT=SUCCESS  APPID=application_1434535025160_0001    CONTAINERID=container_1434535025160_0001_01_000001
2015-06-17 11:42:43,997 FATAL org.apache.hadoop.yarn.event.AsyncDispatcher: Error in dispatcher thread
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Wrong FS: hdfs://var/log/hadoop-yarn, expected: hdfs://cdh-master:8020
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.checkPath(FileSystem.java:645)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.getPathName(DistributedFileSystem.java:193)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.access$000(DistributedFileSystem.java:105)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$18.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1128)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$18.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1124)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystemLinkResolver.resolve(FileSystemLinkResolver.java:81)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.getFileStatus(DistributedFileSystem.java:1124)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.logaggregation.LogAggregationService.verifyAndCreateRemoteLogDir(LogAggregationService.java:192)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.logaggregation.LogAggregationService.initApp(LogAggregationService.java:319)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.logaggregation.LogAggregationService.handle(LogAggregationService.java:443)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.logaggregation.LogAggregationService.handle(LogAggregationService.java:67)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.event.AsyncDispatcher.dispatch(AsyncDispatcher.java:173)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.event.AsyncDispatcher$1.run(AsyncDispatcher.java:106)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
2015-06-17 11:42:44,000 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.application.Application: Adding container_1434535025160_0001_01_000001 t
o application application_1434535025160_0001
2015-06-17 11:42:44,001 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.event.AsyncDispatcher: Exiting, bbye..
2015-06-17 11:42:44,034 INFO org.mortbay.log: Stopped HttpServer2$SelectChannelConnectorWithSafeStartup@0.0.0.0:8042
2015-06-17 11:42:44,035 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.ContainerManagerImpl: Applications still running : [application_14345350
```

I've seen this error

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Wrong FS:
hdfs://var/log/hadoop-yarn, expected: hdfs://cdh-master:8020
```

in the following post: [Failed to start Jobtracker and Tasktracker in CDH pseudo cluster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18001763/failed-to-start-jobtracker-and-tasktracker-in-cdh-pseudo-cluster), but this did not helped me much.

Does anyone has an idea?

Thx

Answer (score 2):

Change the property `yarn.nodemanager.remote-app-log-dir` in `yarn-site.xml` config file either to:

```xml
<property>  
  <name>yarn.nodemanager.remote-app-log-dir</name>
  <value>hdfs://cdh-master:8020/var/log/hadoop-yarn/apps</value>
</property>
```

or

```xml
<property>  
  <name>yarn.nodemanager.remote-app-log-dir</name>
  <value>/var/log/hadoop-yarn/apps</value>
</property>
```

The second option will use the default filesystem that should be set to HDFS anyway.